# Backbone Where function on an attribute which is an object

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a backbone model like so:

```
    Name: Test1
 size: {Key: "M" Value: "Med"}
```

Now I am trying to get a total for the key M. the function below is not working:

```
getTotals: function(property) {
        return this.where({ size: { Key: property }}).length;
    }
```

I call it like so:

```
collection.getTotals("M")
```

Is there a way to do this with the backbone where function?

Comment: what do you expect `length` to come from?

Comment: this.where() returns a collection of objects. It will return the length of the collection. http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to do this with backbone's `where` method.  Have a look at the documentation (http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where) and consider what it says: "useful for *simple* cases of filter" (emphasis added).

Yours is not a simple case because the value of `size` is an object, but we still use filter:

```
collection.filter(function(model) {
    return model.get('size').Key == 'M'
});
```